# RAILS: How to set width for a textarea in bootstrap 3 panel?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a piece of erb code with a `textarea`. I used `style="min-width: 100%"` to make the area expanding to 100% width. But the `style` does not work at all.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <!--panel-->
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-<%=BUTTONS_CLS['left-span#']%> form-group">
                    <b><%=t('Batch#')%></b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-<%=BUTTONS_CLS['right-span#']%> form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" style="min-width: 100%"><%= @part_production.requirement  %></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the html source code of the `textarea`:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
<textarea id="comment" class="form-control" rows="1" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

How to style the width of the textarea (percentage of the panel. without specifying certain px)?

Comment: The parent column class is limiting the size. Try changing it from `col-sm-5` to `col-sm-8` or whatever will let it grow to take the available space of the row. Not sure what the column to the left of it is since your rails code is there, not the rendered html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `col-sm-12`

like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
<textarea id="comment" class="form-control" rows="1" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

the reason maybe it won't get 100% percent is because of the `col-sm-5` class.

Answer (score 1):

You just check this code..

Try add `min-width: 100%` to style of your textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
```

otherwise try this..

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set style inline you can just add the css to your CSS files. 100% will expand to it's parents size.

```
textarea.form-control{ width: 100% !important; }
```

may be you want to consider to change your HTML markup to:

```
<div class="col-sm-5"><div class="form-group">...</div>...
```

instead of doing form-group and col in one div.